# How to create and write a module for automation test framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

i'm junior qa automation and have as a task write module for header and category. Our QA senior used webdriver + java + cucumber. Please show me some example how to write some module

Comment: The reason for the downvotes is because you are looking for a tutorial and/or code to be written for you. Try searching google for a Java tutorial for modules, and once you understand the concept of Java modules (or have attempted some code, and it's not working), you can come back to us with a repeatable example of where your problem is. 

We aren't a code writing service, and we aren't here to give people tutorials. We're here essentially to give you advice on how to fix your broken code.

See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for more information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go with page object model. It's simple only. Refer this link.
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-pattern-model-page-factory/

Ex: Keep Header.java and Move the locator elements to Header.java
Similarly Catergory.java and Move the locator elements to Category.java

Then SampleTest.java, Call the locator method  in the test file.... That's all.......